# How can I install binutils from source?

Tags: installation

```
uname -a: Linux ubuntu 3.5.0-23-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 24 13:05:29 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# apt-get source binutils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Ignore unavailable target release 'stable' of package 'binutils'
E: Unable to find a source package for
```

I did `apt-get update` before typing the command. How can I get binutils? I am using Ubuntu 12.10.

I am following the instruction on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Toolchain/Crosscompilers/ARMEABIToolchain

I am stuck at the first line.

I did `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:germia/archive3` previously, however I got some errors then, I did `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:germia/archive3` to undo the setting. I wonder if my problem is related wtih this PPA?

Comment: Are you trying to compile from source? The source package is actually named `binutils-source` - GNU assembler, linker and binary utilities (source) you can run `apt-cache search binutils` to find the package.

Comment: If you just want to install it however `sudo apt-get install binutils`.  If you want the source you need to [enable the source repositories](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu) first.

Comment: terry wang: yes I am trying to compile from the source file. apt-get install binutils-source outputs E: Ignore unavailable target release 'stable' of package 'binutils-source'

Comment: I just ran in my home folder (not as root) `apt-get source binutils` on 12.04. Worked for me. If you are worried the ppa is the culprit, check `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/germia*`. If it's still there, remove it and run `sudo apt-get update` afterwards. Then try again.

Comment: phipsalabim: thank you, I deleted the germia files, but after apt-get update, I get the same error.

Comment: Do you have `APT::Default-Release` set to `stable`? If so, then that could be the cause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try specifying the target directly.

on quantal ([see here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=quantal&keywords=binutils))

run as normal user

```
apt-get source binutils=2.22.90.20120924-0ubuntu2
```

Comment: I could not vote up because of my rank. thank you, it solved my problem and it is a good method to learn.

Comment: no problem, glad it worked. don't worry about upvotes they're irrelevant.